# Is "together" used as a noun in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

> 1. 'It took us 22 years to tie the knot.. we may not **have long together** but I'll treasure these memories forever'. (from [Source
>      1](https://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/news/scottish-news/it-took-22-years-tie-7365225))
> 2. “Every time we touch I melt.” Our eyes locked for a long moment afterwards, and I regretted the fact we were in public and didn't
>      **have long together**. (from [Source 2](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=d2g8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT90&lpg=PT90&dq=%22have%20long%20together%22&source=bl&ots=tVCTN9LhiZ&sig=ACfU3U1yvuCKw2LR5CTAUd6qSSYzGKLNww&hl=ko&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22have%20long%20together%22&f=false))
> 3. 'We didn't have **long together**, Roger, your real grandfather. (from [Source 3](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=EU2WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22have%20long%20together%22&source=bl&ots=iu9ofK2had&sig=ACfU3U1hM9L_mM_iSB9OYQ8Wd9fW-Cq-Sg&hl=ko&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22have%20long%20together%22&f=false))

It seems like **"together"** is used as a noun and **"long"** is an adjective modifying **"together"**. 
It's my first time I've come across this expression, but it doesn't sound quite correct, because I couldn't find out **"together"** can be used as a noun in any dictionaries.

So, my opinion is **"long together"** is the direct object of **"have"** because other than this, there seems to be no way to analyze those sentences.

Comment: Or "long" is a noun: "1. A long time:" and "together" is an adverb modifying what's essentially "a long time". Under your reading (ie., "long" being an adjective modifying the noun "together), you should be able to remove the adjective and leave "together" as the object of "have". You end up with "we didn't have together". Does that sound right?

Comment: @Zebrafish I think you're right.

Comment: Agree, "long together" just means "**a long time together**".  You could say "`we didn't have long`", but not "`we didn't have together`".